# Write a program that randomly generates a numbers and saves all its divisors in a file named "Q1.txt"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

can anyone help me
Write a program that randomly generates a number between 10 and 10000 and after displaying it, saves all its divisors in a file named Q1.txt
my code:

```
import random
import math
random_number = random.randint(10, 10000)
print("Random number:", random_number)
for i in range(1,random_number+1):
    if(random_number%i==0):
        print(i)
f = open('Q1.txt', mode='w')
res = f.write(str(i))
f.close()
```

it only shows last number of divisors, i want all of them

Comment: Are you opening and closing that file over and over in your loop? If so, you'll want to append (`mode="a"`), not write (`mode="w"`). But it's much more efficient to just open it once, before the loop, and close it once after. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Opening a file in write mode will delete all existing contents each time

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with where in your code you're opening and writing to the file, but I can't tell because you've pasted it out-of-line. Please send the whole code formatted as Chris suggests.

Comment: @journpy, please don't make this kind of edit. We don't know what OP's code actually looks like and since Python is sensitive to whitespace you may have changed the semantics of the question. Only OP knows what their actual code is, and only they should change it.

Comment: @yarpa, I'm going to roll journpy's edit back. Feel free to change the code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for editing, @yarpa. The answer you seek is in the marked duplicate. Please follow the link in the blue box at the top of the page.

Comment: @Chris but it's not a loop. it is change every time and have different values –

Comment: @yarpa, it's not clear where the last two snippets go in relation to the code in the first block. If they're not in the loop, are you putting them _after_ the loop? At that point, what value does `i` have?

Comment: @Chris "i" generated randomly every time, and I want to save divisors of it in a .txt file

Comment: @yarpa, it's generated randomly each time through the loop. But _after_ the loop, the loop is done. If you're waiting until after the loop to save the value of `i`, you'll just get the last value. I suggest you look at the question I marked as a duplicate again.

Comment: @yarpa, have you figured out how to get this to work?

Comment: no :( and i'm so confused

Comment: @yarpa, do you understand why `i` has the value it has (just the last value) when you write to the file?

Comment: i've done it. thanks